# How to show color attribute with sku id in magento

Tags: magento

I need to show color attribute of other product with sku id. 
For example. I am on product A page. I have SKU of other product(B,C) . I need to display other product color ,size with SKU.

How can I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can fetch the product by sku something like code below and use/display any information you want to display.

```
 $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$sku); //$sku will be your product's sku.
```

if it don't show all the details then you can try to load the product by it's something like this code

```
 $productId = $product->getIdBySku($sku); //$sku will be your prdouct's sku
 if ($productId) {
    $product->load($productId);
 }
```

if you have more than one sku than create the array and call it in loop.